# How to check in python if record exists or not in ms access

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

Im making a simple form in python that inserts, deletes, updates and searches records. I want my code to check if a record exists against cnic number entered by user, if not then return a value or True/False. Any idea on what i could use?
This is my code.

```
def DeleteRecord():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cnic = cnicEntery.get()

    validation = re.search(r"^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$",cnic)
    exists=Dlookup("cnic","Student","Criteria=cnic")
    if cnic=='':
        message.config(text="Enter CNIC# first!",foreground="red")
    elif validation == None:
        message.config(text="Invalid CNIC! Enter another!",foreground="red")
    elif exists=='':
        message.config("No record found to delete! Please try again!")
    else:
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Student WHERE cnic = ?', (cnic))
        conn.commit()
        message.config(text="Record has been deleted successfully!", foreground="green")
```

I tried using Dlookup but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to test for the existence of the row ahead of time. Just try to do the delete and then check `.rowcount` to see if any rows were actually deleted:

```py
crsr.execute("DELETE FROM Student WHERE cnic = ?", cnic)
if crsr.rowcount:
    print("Row deleted.")
else:
    print("Row not found.")
```